# AWS-EC2 Redis-server RDB snapshot write error

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, redis

I have a web application running on Laravel5.2 framework, with session driver set to redis with following AWS setup.

- Instance-1: Running web application, with Redis configurations in .env file as follow

  1. Redis-host: `aws-private-ip-of-instance-2`
  2. Redis-password: `NULL`
  3. Redis-port: `6379`
- Instance-2: Redis-server running with following configuration

  1. Bind `aws-private-ip-of-instance-2` and 127.0.0.1
  2. Working directory `/var/lib/redis` with 775 permission, and ower-group is redis.
  3. RDB snapshot name `dump.rdb` with 660 permission, and ower-group is redis.

> NOTE: In AWS inbound rule for port `6379` is configured for
>   Instance-2.

Everything works fine, until redis tries to write the data on the RDB file. Following error shows on front-end.

> MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently
>   not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are
>   disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.

While in the logs of Redis server i got following data.

```
4873:M 23 Sep 10:08:15.028 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
4873:M 23 Sep 10:08:15.028 * Background saving started by pid 7392
7392:C 23 Sep 10:08:15.028 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Read-only file system
4873:M 23 Sep 10:08:15.128 # Background saving error
```

Things I have tried

- Add `vm.overcommit_memory = 1` to /etc/sysctl.conf, as suggested in [Redis-administraition-blog](https://redis.io/topics/admin)
- Change path to `dump.rdb` file to `tmp` folder and change permissions to `777`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is very embarrassing to post answer of own question, which was a really stupid mistake. But hope new folks here learns from my mistake too.

- So first thing I have done is enable detail logs for redis-server in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file by changing `log_level` option to `debug`.
- Observe the logs and understand that my redis port `6379` was open for everyone on internet.

So from logs I observe that someone else's server is spoofing into my redis server and making it slave of it. And as my redis server is configure in a way that slave is `read-only`, when i try to access my redis-server it throw error of read-only.

- After applying the fire-wall for redis server port, I have not encounter this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This [other Stack Exchange thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/943284/redis-with-custom-data-dir-systemd-config-file-changed-automatically/943335#943335) might help, since you are using a custom /tmp dir for data:

> The simple way to do this is to run `systemctl edit redis`. This will create an override drop-in file `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d/override.conf`, in which you can place your changes (and the proper section):
>
> `[Service]`
> `ReadWriteDirectories=-/my/custom/data/dir`
>
> You may also create that directory and place files ending in `.conf` in it manually. But do not leave the directory empty, as this will disable the service.
>
> In either case, run `systemctl daemon-reload` and you are ready to restart your service.

Many threads also point to filesystem inconsistency as root cause. Since you are using EC2, check this [AWS forums post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176052):

> To fix this, you will have to:
>
> 1. Stop the instance
> 2. Detach the root volume of your instance
> 3. Attach the volume as a data volume to any running Linux instance in the same availability zone
> 4. Perform a filesystem check (fsck) on the volume and fix the issues
> 5. Detach the volume and attach it back to your instance as it's root volume
> 6. Boot back instance and verify if the volume was able to mount successfully

As a last resort, terminate the instance if possible.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, my entire filesystem is not becoming Read-only because when this error arise, writing logs into log files is working all right without issue. So I don't think this issue has anything to do with filesystem. Only the `dump.rdb` file which was created by redis it self with `redis` user is becoming Read-only.

Comment: Edited with another possible cause. Thanks!

Comment: I saw your edit and also read the suggested thread you have provided. But that's not my case at all. I have not changed any default setting. I have just tried to write a data in `/tmp` folder, which was also not working. That's what I mean by writing section `THINGS I HAVE TRIED` (but not worked).

Comment: But did you add your /tmp dir to ReadWriteDirectories config?

Comment: Hey @Fabio. I do not have to do that as I have kept the default setting as it is. When I changed it and tried, redis was working fine initially, but after some time error start coming. So I am trying to say that even after changing the Directory of .rdb file issue persist same as default settings.

Comment: I added back the instructions related to filesystem inconsistency, in case it helps someone else. You tried that, right?

Comment: So is it possible that if filesystem became Read-only, still every program running on that server are able to write their logs into file?

Comment: It doesn't make sense -- that's why I think your case might be related to Redis' ReadWriteDirectories config.

Comment: No it's not because I have not changed anything from default config of Redis.